# Main thread to wait two parallel threads children java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java-threads, cyclicbarrier

first what i am trying to do:

During the main thread execution i want to pause the main thread and start two parallel threads. As soon as both this parallel threads terminate, i'd like to start again with the main thread.

What i tried:

```
    ...
    ...
    main thread is executing
    ...
    ...
CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier(2);
Thread child1 = new Thread(new ThreadBuilderTask(barrier,0));
Thread child2 = new Thread(new ThreadBuilderTask(barrier,1));

child1.start();
child2.start(); 

/* Now i'm expecting that child1 and child2 are running in parallel calling their fooFunction */

child1.join();
child2.join(); 
/*Now i'm expecting that main thread will wait for child1and also for child2 (that are running in parallel).*/

... main thread starts again after both child1 and child2 finished (reached the await of the barrier) 
... (break point set here, never reached)
...
```

Thread builder custom class

```
public class ThreadBuilderTask implements Runnable{
    private CyclicBarrier barrier;
    private int index;
    ...setters and getters..

    @Override
    public void run() {
        fooFunction(this.getIndex());
        try {
            this.getBarrier().await();
        } catch (InterruptedException | BrokenBarrierException e) {
            return;
        }
    }

    public ThreadBuilderTask(CyclicBarrier barrier,int index){
      this.barrier = barrier;
      this.index = index;
    }

    public fooFunction(int index){
        //Something taking some seconds to execute
    }
```

It's not clear what is happening here but it is definetely not working. As soon as i call join everything stops and the main thread never restart. (I put a breakpoint after the joins to see when the main thread restarts).

Maybe there is a bit of confusion with these concepts and also i'm not sure if i need to use both the barrier and the joins or simply one of those techniques.

Thanks

Davide

Comment: Do child1 and child2 finish?

Comment: Are you tied to using `CyclicBarrier` or something like this? This can be achieved easily with `CompletableFuture`

Comment: I'm pretty sure that they finish, what if they throw an error? Like a null pointer?

Comment: No i'm not bound to use CyclicBarrier at all. I will look for this CompletableFuture thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments I'd also suggest to use `CompletableFuture`. A very basic example of your described requirements could look like this:

```java
final Runnable runnable1 = ...;
final Runnable runnable2 = ...;

CompletableFuture<Void> future1 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(runnable1);
CompletableFuture<Void> future2 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(runnable2);

CompletableFuture.allOf(future1, future2).get(); // waits for both runnables to finish
```

You might want to add more/some exception handling to this example. But it should give an idea how this might work.

Comment: It seems like this might be a solution, now however i have to solve the roles issues as i'm creating a thread inside the EJB container and there is some mess with roles but thanks

Comment: I confirm that this answerd the question as they both run in parallel and the main thread waits (with the allOf ) the two thread to execute.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider to use Java **CompletableFuture** to achieve the objective.

Using its functions like **supplyAsync** or **runAsync** you may start child threads and join their respective result  in the end. Or you can simply let the main thread wait until the subsequent threads completes.

Recently I managed to implement a sample scatter-gather function using the same class.

Check Java Doc for more offerings and to find best available function: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html